# Using AssertJ to assert multiple JsonNode paths on the same object?

Tags: java, json, jackson, assertj

I'm using assertj-core 3.9.1, but I also tested this with the latest available to me, 3.16.1.

I'm trying to make some assertj assertions a little cleaner. We often assert multiple subproperties at a non-trivial hierarchy level, for various kinds of objects. I've been using "extracting" to pull simple properties from an object, but what I'm trying to do now is a little more complicated, and it's not working.  What I'm seeing SEEMS like a bug in assertj, but I'm not sure why it's doing what it's doing.

I'm starting with something like this:

```
assertThat(expression).at("/content/liability").asText()).isEqualTo("CRU");
assertThat(expression).at("/content/enterpriseType").asText()).isEqualTo("GBS");
```

I'd like to instead do something like this:

```
assertThat(expression)
    .extracting(jn -> jn.at("/content/liability").asText(),
                jn -> jn.at("/content/enterpriseType").asText())
    .containsExactly("CRU", "GBS");
```

This fails, basically saying that I expected "[]" (an empty list) to be equal to ["CRU", "GBS"].

I still have the original assertions above this, using the same expression, so I know the data is there.  The expression returns a structure like this:

```
{
  "content": {
    ...
    "enterpriseType": "GBS",
    ...
    "liability": "CRU",
    ...
  }
}
```

So, I then tried changing the assertion to this:

```
assertThat(expression))
    .extracting(jn -> textAtPath(jn, "/content/liability"),
                jn -> textAtPath(jn, "/content/enterpriseType"))
    .containsExactly(tuple("CRU", "GBS"));
```

With:

```
private String textAtPath(JsonNode node, String path) {
    return node.at(path).asText();
}
```

And then I ran the test with a breakpoint in "textAtPath".  What I saw there looked normal, until I looked closer.  When I viewed the value of "node", I saw something that looked very much like the structure I showed above, but not quite:

```
{
  ...
  "enterpriseType": "GBS",
  ...
  "liability": "CRU",
  ...
}
```

For some reason, the value passed to the lambda passed to "extracting()" was the CHILD node of the original structure.

I tried changing the test so the two path strings were "/liability" and "/enterpriseType".  The test passed.  I'm not going to leave it like this, because this just doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is discussed in https://github.com/joel-costigliola/assertj-core/issues/1954.

The subtlety here is that if expression is an iterable, assertThat(expression) will provide iterable assertions and `extracting` will be applied on the iterable elements.

On the other hand if `assertThat(expression)` has returned object assertion, `extracting` would be applied to expression.

I also strongly suggest to use [JsonUnit](https://github.com/lukas-krecan/JsonUnit) for JSON assertions.

Comment: For later readers, the alternative, as you state in the issue, is to use assertThatObject instead of assertThat. That allows for a minimal change to get this working, but I acknowledge that using JsonUnit has some advantages.